# How to use column value as column header?

Tags: sql, pivot-table

I have a table like this:

```
ItemID    PartID   PartName   PartValue
  1         1        N1         v1
  1         2        N2         v2
  1         3        N3         v3
...
  2         1        N1          u1
  2         2        N2          u2
  2         3        N3          u3
...
```

Can I use a sql select statement to get following table?

```
ItemID    N1    N2    N3 ...
  1       v1    v2    v3 ...
  2       u1    u2    u3 ...
 ...
```

The problem is I don't know how many part names are there, so there might be also n4, n5, n6 ...so need dynamically select. I see some pivot examples but looks like it can be used when I know how many part names. If I don't know, how should I deal with this? Thanks!

Comment: Quick drive-by hint at a solution - What about using a stored prodecure with a for loop to generate a view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done using dynamic SQL to build a pivot statement. Awkward, ugly, but it works, and can work quite efficiently. Please review my first answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7822004/pivots-with-dynamic-columns-in-sql-server) for details.

Answer (score 2):

If you can't predefine the columns in your output then PIVOT is not appropriate.  Instead dynamic SQL (which should generally be avoided) is a way forward.

See [SQL Server 2005 Pivot on Unknown Number of Columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/213702/sql-server-2005-pivot-on-unknown-number-of-columns)

Answer (score 1):

The below has been tested in SQL-Server, but I think the principals can be applied to whatever RDBMS you are using.

```
CREATE TABLE #t (ItemID INT, PartID INT, PartName VARCHAR(2), PartValue VARCHAR(2))
INSERT #t VALUES (1, 1, 'N1', 'V1'), (1, 2, 'N2', 'V2'), (1, 3, 'N3', 'V3'), (2, 1, 'N1', 'V1'), (2, 2, 'N2', 'V2'), (2, 3, 'N3', 'V3')

DECLARE @SQL VARCHAR(MAX)
SELECT  @SQL = ISNULL(@SQL, '') + 
                        ', (    SELECT  PartValue 
                                FROM    #t t' + Rownum + ' 
                                WHERE   t' + Rownum + '.ItemID = t.ItemID
                                AND     t' + Rownum + '.PartName = ''' + PartName + ''' 
                            ) [' + PartName + ']'
FROM    (   SELECT  PartName, CONVERT(VARCHAR, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY PartName)) [RowNum]
            FROM    #t
            GROUP BY PartName
        ) d
SET @SQL = 'SELECT ItemID' + @SQL + ' FROM (SELECT DISTINCT ItemID FROM #t) t'
EXEC (@SQL)

DROP TABLE #t
```

Note - This is likely to get inefficient if you have a a lot of data, with a lot fo columns