# Transpose SQL result set

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, pivot

I have data in the following format:

```
Machine |  week_end  | widgets
 A      | 05-26-2013 | 5
 B      | 05-26-2013 | 4
 A      | 04-01-2013 | 6
 B      | 04-01-2013 | 0
```

I want my result set to look as follows:

```
Machine | 05-26-2013 | 04-01+2013 | ...
 A      | 5          | 6          |
 B      | 4          | 0          |
```

I'm not quite sure how to proceed here--how does one transpose a table like this without having to specify the week ends (or whatever) explicitly in the query? (DB is SQL Server 2008.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to do some research on the SQL `PIVOT` function. It will allow you to turn rows into columns. This should be what you are looking for, once you find out how to apply it.

Check out this link: [Using PIVOT and UNPIVOT](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

Comment: One question, though: I'd like to avoid having to type in the column names by hand, as there are lots of them. Is there a way to avoid this, or do I have to manually type in the col names?

Comment: No, you can add them dynamically. Try Googleing "Dynamic column names SQL pivot" or check out this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7822004/pivots-with-dynamic-columns-in-sql-server