# SQL How to display row on column

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, row

I have this table

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[MONITOR.Dati_Attivita]
(
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [IDEsecuzione] [int] NOT NULL,
    [IDIndice] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Valore] [nvarchar](100) NOT NULL,
    [IDRipetizione] [int] NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_Monitor_Dati_Attivita] 
      PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([ID] ASC)
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

So I would like to `SELECT` the result set,

I try this:

```
SELECT IDEsecuzione, Valore, IDRipetizioe
```

The result is

```
1 -  100  - 1
1 - 'abc' - 1
1 - 'VVV' - 1
2 - 'aaa' - 1
2 - 'bbb' - 1
2 - 'ccc' - 1
```

But I would like to display result set like this:

```
1 - 100 - abc - VVV - 1
2 - aaa- bbb - ccc - 1
```

Can you help me?

Regards

Comment: possible duplicate of [Transpose SQL result set](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18765578/transpose-sql-result-set)

Comment: I didn't think SQL supports such a thing, but @NoComments may have a good point. Are you using this inside of an application? If you are, you can use the regular select statement and format the results the way you'd like inside the application.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13372276/simple-way-to-transpose-columns-and-rows-in-sql

Comment: Take a look at a Pivot example for transposing rows into columns: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to make a query with group\_concat in sql server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17591490/how-to-make-a-query-with-group-concat-in-sql-server)

Comment: I think is not about transpose rows into columns (pivot) it is rows into one column with hyphen separated values http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17591490/how-to-make-a-query-with-group-concat-in-sql-server

Comment: Do you want that data concatenated into a single row/column - or do you want the data converted from multiple rows into multiple columns?  It's not exactly clear what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To concatenate a column over rows, use the [FOR XML PATH](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/ms178107.aspx) method.

```
    SELECT DISTINCT
        IDEsecuzione,
        Valore = SUBSTRING((SELECT ' - ' + t1.Valore 
                            FROM MONITOR.Dati_Attivita t1 
                            WHERE t1.IDEsecuzione = t2.IDEsecuzione 
                            FOR XML PATH('')), 4, 9999),
        IDRipetizione
    FROM MONITOR.Dati_Attivita t2
```